# Filter facets on facet.missing = 0

Tags: solr, solr4

Is it possible to get only facet fields for which all results have values? So, basically those that will have facet.missing count = 0.

Comment: I'm not making this an answer because I'm not sure, but I suspect the only way to do that would be to retrieve the missing count and then ignore the entire facet field block whenever it's not zero.

Comment: You could do this in a two step process, retrieving zero rows for each facet, but getting the missing counts. Then repeat the search with actual facet rows returned but only for facets with 100% coverage for matching records.